# pytables add repetitive subclass as column

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I am creating a HDF5 file with strict parameters. It has 1 table consisting of variable columns.  At one point the columns become repetitive with the different data being appended. Apparently, I can't add loop inside IsDescription class.  Currently the class Segments has been added under class Summary_data twice.  I need to call segments_k 70 times.  What is the best approach to it?  Thank you.

```
class Header(IsDescription):
    _v_pos    = 1
    id        = Int16Col(dflt=1, pos = 0)
    timestamp = Int16Col(dflt=1, pos = 1)

class Segments(IsDescription):
    segment_id      = Int16Col(dflt=1, pos = 0)
    segment_quality = Float32Col(dflt=1, pos = 1)
    segment_length  = Float32Col(dflt=1, pos = 2)

class Summary_data(IsDescription):
    latency     = Float32Col(dflt=1, pos = 2)
    segments_k  = Int16Col(dflt=1, pos = 4)
    segments_k0 = Segments()
    segments_k1 = Segments()

class Everything(IsDescription):
    header       = Header()
    summary_data = Summary_data()
    
def write_new_file():
    h5file = "results.hdf5"
    with open_file(h5file, mode = "w") as f:
        root    = f.root
        table1  = f.create_table(root, "Table1", Everything)
        row     = table1.row
        length  = [[23.5, 16.3], [8, 6]]
        quality = [[0.9, 0.7], [0.6, 0.4]]
        for i in range(2):
            row['header/id'] = i
            row['header/timestamp'] = i * 2.
            row['summary_data/latency'] = 0.0
            row['summary_data/segments_k'] = 0

            for data in range(2):
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_id'] = data
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_quality'] = quality[data][i]
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_length'] = length[data][i]
            row.append()
```

Comment: I see you are trying to use Nested Columns. It looks like each `summary_data/segments_k#` is nested under the previous summary. So `summary_data/segments_k1` is nested under `summary_data/segments_k0`, which is nested under `summary_data/segments_k`. Was that your intend? Either way, I think it will be easier to define the table schema using a NumPy dtype (instead of `tables.IsDescription`). The advantage? You can create the `np.dtype()` as a dictionary with a loop. Once I understand the desired structure, I can show how that would be done.

Comment: The hdf5 file is a step for further processing. I need to preserve columns naming convention.  The Header and Summary_data are the log summary. Then, next 70 Segments are filled with different data for each segment.   Segment_k is part of Summary_data, but segment_k[i] is segment.  The opened hdf5 file should have 0 in the first row in the header; the header{0}, summary_data{0} and summary_data->segments_k0{0}, segments_k1{0} and etc in the second row.(It might be segments_k{0}, segments_k{1}... but I don't know if it is possible).The third row should have names of all parameters. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the schema, (It doesn't help that nested columns are hard to explain in words). I think you have `segments_k0{0}` and `segments_k1{0}` are nested under `summary_data`. See image in the "answer" below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand, and will attempt to explain how I did this (and how to extend to handle all 70 segments). As an aside, your nested fields are exceedingly complex, far more complicated than anything I've seen. Are you sure you need this many levels of nested fields?

The key is using a `np.dtype()` to define the table description. I always use them to define my tables, not the `IsDescription` method. (I use NumPy to process my HDF5 data, so I'm comfortable with the module.) In your case, you need a dytpe because it is the only way I know to create your complex table structure with code. Otherwise you will be creating `IsDescription` entires for hours. :-)

The code below uses 3 different methods to create 3 tables (schema and data in each table should be identical). An explanation for each:

1. **Table 1**: is created with your code. It uses the`IsDescription` method to create 3
   `summary_data/segments_k#` entries. (I added `segments_k2 = Segments()` to `class Summary_data()` ). Note this line of code:
   `print (tb.description.dtype_from_descr(Everything) )`. It prints
   the equivalent np.dtype for `Everything` description used by Table1.
   I referenced this for Tables 2 and 3 below.
2. **Table 2** description references np.dtype `tb2_dt`. I copied/pasted
   this from the previous output. I could have referenced as a variable,
   but I want you to see it to understand what I did for Table 3. Code to populate the table is the same as Table 1.
3. **Table 3** description references np.dtype `tb3_dt`. This is where it things get tricky. The np.dtype structure is COMPLICATED: it is a list of tuples and tuples of lists. The dtype is built from `seg_kn_list` and `tb3_dt_list`. Code to populate the table is the same as Table 1 and 2.

To get this to work for 70 segments, "all" you have to do is change the 2 `range(3)` arguments that create `seg_kn_tlist` and populate the data rows. (Of course, you also need to provide the data.)

Code below:

```
    import tables as tb
    import numpy as np

    h5file = "SO_64449277np.h5"
    with tb.open_file(h5file, mode = "w") as h5f:
        length  = [[23.5, 16.3], [8, 6], [11.0, 7.7]]
        quality = [[0.9, 0.7], [0.6, 0.4], [0.8, 0.5]]

        root    = h5f.root
        table1  = h5f.create_table(root, "Table1", Everything)
        print (tb.description.dtype_from_descr(Everything) )

        row     = table1.row
        for i in range(2):
            row['header/id'] = i
            row['header/timestamp'] = i * 2.
            row['summary_data/latency'] = 0.0
            row['summary_data/segments_k'] = 0

            for data in range(3):
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_id'] = data
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_quality'] = quality[data][i]
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_length'] = length[data][i]
            row.append()

        tb2_dt = np.dtype([('header', [('id', '<i2'), ('timestamp', '<i2')]), 
                           ('summary_data', [('latency', '<f4'), ('segments_k', '<i2'), 
                           ('segments_k0', [('segment_id', '<i2'), ('segment_quality', '<f4'), ('segment_length', '<f4')]), 
                           ('segments_k1', [('segment_id', '<i2'), ('segment_quality', '<f4'), ('segment_length', '<f4')]),
                           ('segments_k2', [('segment_id', '<i2'), ('segment_quality', '<f4'), ('segment_length', '<f4')]),
                           ])] )

        table2  = h5f.create_table(root, "Table2", tb2_dt)
        row     = table2.row
        for i in range(2):
            row['header/id'] = i
            row['header/timestamp'] = i * 2.
            row['summary_data/latency'] = 0.0
            row['summary_data/segments_k'] = 0

            for data in range(3):
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_id'] = data
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_quality'] = quality[data][i]
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_length'] = length[data][i]
            row.append()

# Create np.dtype() iteratively
# Start with laency and segments_k, and use a loop to add segments_k# id, quality and length
            
        seg_kn_tlist = [('latency', '<f4'), ('segments_k', '<i2') ]
        for cnt in range(3) :            
            seg_kn_tlist.append( ('segments_k'+str(cnt), 
                                [('segment_id', '<i2'), ('segment_quality', '<f4'), ('segment_length', '<f4')] ) ) 
 
# Finish np.dtype() definition with fileds for header, timestamp and summary_data, followed by tuple with list above         
        tb3_dt_list = [ ('header', [('id', '<i2'), ('timestamp', '<i2')]), ('summary_data', seg_kn_tlist) ]
        
        tb3_dt = np.dtype( tb3_dt_list ) 

        table3  = h5f.create_table(root, "Table3", tb3_dt)
        row     = table3.row
        for i in range(2):
            row['header/id'] = i
            row['header/timestamp'] = i * 2.
            row['summary_data/latency'] = 0.0
            row['summary_data/segments_k'] = 0

            for data in range(3):
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_id'] = data
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_quality'] = quality[data][i]
                row['summary_data/segments_k'+str(data)+'/segment_length'] = length[data][i]
            row.append()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, kcw78.  I truly appreciate it.  Two follow up questions: 1) Is any way possible to iterate through the loop of segments_k incrementing the index instead of appending a number to segments_k?  The easiest thing (theoretically) is to create .json file (I think here they call it metadata).  2) Is any way to create this metadata file and then pass it into the python script?

Comment: I need more details on Q1: what index do you want to increment? Python supports all kinds of loops. For example, you could do `for a_var in a_list:` and use `a_var` as your variable. I'm not familiar with JSON - Sorry. HDF5 can tag objects with 'attributes' which are bits of info that apply to the entire group or table. Is that what you mean by 'metadata'?

Comment: kcw78, I need to create a list to iterate through segments_k. For example, segments_k[0], segments_k[1], ... segments_k[69].   Is there a way to achieve it? This file will be used somewhere else, and the segments will be extracted via loop.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You can probably use list compression to populate the list. What goes in the list? Do you want segment names like this `seg_list=[ 'segments_k[0]', 'segments_k[1]', 'segments_k[2]', 'segments_k[3]', etc ]`. Or something else?

Comment: Yes, basically to replace seg_kn_tlist.append( ('segments_k'+str(cnt), ...) with segments_k[i].

Comment: That was supposed to be list _**comprehension**-. :-) Basically you want to collapse my loop to a single line. The list I create combines lists and and a list of tuples.  Here is a simple example to create a list for 5 k# values: `segk_list = ['segments_k['+str(cnt)+']' for cnt in range(5) ]`. Print when done to see the contents.

Comment: I moved to the new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615524/using-h5t-array-in-python . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not following your explanation in the comments. Below is an screen grab from **HDFView** showing the schema/table layout. As I see it, `segments_k0{0}` and `segments_k1{0}` are nested under `summary_data`.
See how it shows `summary_data->segments_k0{0}`. Is that what you want? 70 nested columns with each with 3 nested columns (`segment_id`, `segment_quality` and `segment_length`)?
[image: HDFView image]

Or, do you just want `segments_k0{0}` nested under the `0` row.?
I created a second table (Table2) with that schema. See the screen grab below.
Notice that `segments_k0{0}` is not preceded by `summary_data->` (it's not nested).
[image]

Either of these is possible when you enter the description using an `np.dtype()`. You can define dtypes with a dictionary and populate the  field names and formats programmatically. The second table is easier to define. I want to be sure which you want before I show you how to create the `np.dtype()`.

Comment: The first scenario is correct.   Is it also possible to modify it so the sumary_data->segments_k{0} iterates up to summary_data->segments_k{69}?

Comment: @samsara please check this answer (to your other question): https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626281/7185263